# How do I find out for certain if mod_rewrite for Apache is installed

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've got Apache 2 installed on a Suse machine. I've gone through its configuration files, checked out which modules are installed in Yast and even tried writing a rewrite rule in a .htaccess which doesn't work. I can't seem to find mod_rewrite anywhere.

I take it this mean that mod_rewrite is not installed? How can I find out for sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"/usr/sbin/httpd -l" will list your compiled-in modules, and "/usr/sbin/httpd -M" will list your included modules as per your current configuration file.

Naturally, you may have httpd in a different path.

Typically, the list of compiled-in modules is short, and the list of loaded modules somewhat longer.
If it's in the list of loaded modules, it looks like "rewrite_module (shared)".

Answer (score 1):

Drop a `RewriteEngine On` into the main config, and do a configtest.  If it passes, `mod_rewrite` is installed (possibly built-in), if it errors out saying that `RewriteEngine` is an unknown directive, then it's not installed.

Also, I'd be surprised if the server error log didn't indicate that the htaccess file failed to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple phpinfo() will list the available modules.